# Meteor Collection not displaying in Mongo show collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have created a collection called Nodes and have defined it as follows:
(located in project/lib so it has access to both client and server)

```
Nodes = new Mongo.Collection('nodes');
Nodes.allow({
    insert: function (userId, node) {
        return !!userId;
    }
});
```

I have an insert method that lies within the same file:

```
Meteor.methods({
    nodeInsert: function(nodeAttributes) {
        var node = _.extend(nodeAttributes, {
            userId: user._id, author: user.username, submitted: new Date()
        });
        var nodeIdentity = Nodes.insert(node, function(error,result){
            if (error)
            console.log(error);
            if (result)
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
});
```

However, there is no error that is logged on the console.

I have also published this collection on the server:
(located in project/server)

```
Meteor.publish('nodes', function(){ 
    return Nodes.find();
});
```

I have also subscribed to this collection in the template where I use my insert method:
(located in project/lib so it has access to both client and server)

```
Router.route('/workflow',{
    waitOn: function () {
        return [Meteor.subscribe('uploads'),Meteor.subscribe('nodes')];
    },
    action: function () {
        if (this.ready())
            this.render('workflow');
        else
            this.render('Loading');
    }
});
```

Finally, this is how I call my nodeInsert function from my client side template:
(located in project/client)

```
var node = { 
    title: d.title
};
Meteor.call('nodeInsert', node, function(error, result) {
    if (error)
    return throwError(error.reason);
});
```

The node appears to insert into the collection, but when I use the "show collections" command in mongo, the nodes collection does not come up.I also get an internal server error when I do the insert. What may be the reason for this error?

Comment: Are you connecting to the instance of MongoDB that meteor has launched? Or another MongoDB on your system? Have you in fact inserted anything to the collection? It does not exist until you have. Your server error is likely because your method argument is called `nodeAttributes` yet in the insert you reference `node`, which is not declared on the server implementation of the method. That's your "client" declaration, whcich the server knows nothing about. The server errors should show this.

Comment: Yes, I have connected to the instance of Mongo DB that meteor has launched. Also, I didn't paste the whole code in the question but I have the following before i reference "node" in the insert method. var node = _.extend(nodeAttributes, {
            userId: user._id, author: user.username, submitted: new Date()
});

Comment: I am talking about this: `function(nodeAttributes) {
        var nodeIdentity = Nodes.insert(node, function(error,result){`. The `node` there is undefined. Edit your question to show your connection attempt and query on the shell launched. Also you did not answer "Have you actually inserted anything?"

Comment: I have edited my question to show the definition of node on the server side. And yes, I have inserted something. Through console.log statements it seems as though the insert worked.